# Angular / HTML5 will not play audio mpeg from local folder

Tags: html, angular, audio, html5-audio

Does Angular or HTML5 somehow restrict mpeg files from being played from the local folder / localhost?   It works if I use a link to an external CDN.

In HTML5, I have . . . .

```
  <audio controls  autoplay>
    <source src="src/app/sounds/alert.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" >
  </audio>
```

and the player is greyed out like this:

[image]

I have also tried playing the file programmatically, but without success . . .

```
var audio = new Audio("src/app/sounds/alert.mp3");
audio.load()
audio.play();
```

Any Suggestions?   Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? You could check [the browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see if there's an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store the file in the `assets` folder of angular, add the file location to the assets array of `angular.json` (if needed, might be during build!) Then you can reference the file like below!

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="/assets/asdf.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cq1vqh?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fangular.json,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fassets%2Fasdf.mp3&title=node.new%20Starter) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`